# Replacing a text using regex -Spoon

Tags: regex

I am using spoon. In that I need to replace a whole string to null if that string contains my search keyword.
Example :

```
 Search keyword : east
 Str_1 : "the sun rises in the east"
 Str_2 : "my house is facing eastwards"
 Str_3 : "i am a doctor"
```

Expected output:

```
 Str_1: null
 Str_2: null
 Str_3 : "i am a doctor"
```

Can I achieve it through single regex statement. Which means can I use `where` condition in regex (like replace this string to null if contains "east") .

Comment: Is "east" a word known previously that you can use in the regex, or is it unknown until execution, and therefore we have to parse the `Search keyword : <myKeyword>` part ?

Comment: Previously known word.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
"[^"]*east[^"]*"
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/ZTpkXh/1).

It assumes that a string is delimited by quotation marks and it does not contain other quotation marks.

Comment: If you can assume that, can't you just use `.*east.*` ?

Comment: I used your regex and it finds the entire text and replaces it, not only sentence by sentence.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming each string is on its line (or even in a separate variable)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
pattern = '.*east.*'
re.sub(pat, '', str)
```

Example outputs with your strings:

```
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', "the sun rises in the east")
''
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', "my house is facing eastwards")
''
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', "i am a doctor")
"i am a doctor"
```